# java.sql.PreparedStatement.setString Function getting Varchars confused with doubles

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

I have a servlet/tomcat server written in java.

I have a mysql class that I have written, and I have been using the functions in it to insert prepared statements into a mysql database using jdbc.

The function I call uses `java.sql.PreparedStatement.setString` in order to set the paramaters of the prepared statement. This has been working perfectly for thousands of different inputs for months on end without issue.

Recently however, when trying to use the function to insert an ip address into a VARCHAR type mysql column I am getting an exception thrown as follows:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '10.1.1.101'
```

This is bizarre, There is no notion of a DOUBLE anywhere in my code, and a "Show Columns" on the mysql table ensures that the data type is in fact a VARCHAR. I have had my colleagues look at this as well to double check that I wasn't missing something simple. However we are all stumped.

My only theory is that the JDBC driver or the SetText function is taking a liberty and assuming a DOUBLE data type because the first part of the ip address is in the form of XX.XX

Any help would be great, please don't tell me to do obvious stuff like check my column data types etc. I have spent a lot of time double and tripple checking everything.

Comment: Did you update anything (MySQL, the driver, etc)?

Comment: Nope, I didn't introduce anything new except a different type of data being inserted into it.

Comment: Could you post the code ?there may be quotes missing in your code .

Comment: What does the `ParameterMetaData` of the `PreparedStatement` report as the column type? What is the query, and how do you set the parameters?

Comment: @sunleo Are you referring to quotes around the question-mark in the query? I didn't think that was valid. My query is: `INSERT INTO route_table (SYSTEM, IP, PORT) VALUES (?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IP=? AND PORT=?`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel When I try to access the meta data I get the following exception: `java.sql.SQLException: Parameter metadata not available for the given statement`

Comment: @FaddishWorm - can you post the stored procedure code for us?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is not with JDBC Driver. The problem lies with MySQL. Here is what i get on MySQL commadline:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO route_table (SYSTEM, IP, PORT) VALUES ("192.168.1.24:8080","192.168.1.24","8080") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IP=values(IP) AND PORT=values(PORT);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO route_table (SYSTEM, IP, PORT) VALUES ("192.168.1.24:8080","192.168.1.24","8080") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IP=values(IP) AND PORT=values(PORT);
ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '192.168.1.24'
mysql>
```

The problem is , the syntax of `INSERT INTO .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` used by you is incorrect. You have used a keyword `AND` instead of using a `,`*(comma)*. So the query should be:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO route_table (SYSTEM, IP, PORT) VALUES ("192.168.1.24:8080","192.168.1.24","8080") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IP=values(IP), PORT=values(PORT);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @FaddishWorm: The fact that the actual problematic code was buried in the comments probably didn't help. In future, please include your SQL (or whatever code is relevant) in the question to start with. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints